# The linked question shows that the accepted answer has the least votes - should the voting be changed?

Tags: discussion

This happens quite often where the accepted answer does not have the highest votes.

For a simple case in point, see

[Is there an easy way to find the specification pages for old Apple Computers that have now been removed from the Apple Support pages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/390645/237687)

Should this be changed? If we assume the highest answer is "best" then that should be top, but if the accepted answer is always top then what is the point of voting for answers?

Please note I am not after the votes, But talking only about the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the order of the answers yourself if required by selecting Active, Oldest, or Votes. This is a per-user choice.

[image]

But in general there is no need to have the accepted answer also have the highest number of votes. "Accept" is just the way the OP uses to indicate which answer they liked best (so it's kind of like a super-vote). This may be different from what other users think (and vote).

In the specific case this is rather obvious: The OP is asking

> I'm aware that multiple third-party websites exist that have this info, but is there an easy-to-find list of archived URLs for the spec pages for these older models that were previously contained on the Apple Support pages?

which actually only the accepted answer covers. But others consider the links to 3rd party information more helpful, so the voting differs.

Comment: Ok, thanks for a good explanation.

Comment: The OP may not have a choice yet, so will just accept the first answer that addresses a specific issue.  That's not necessarily the answer the OP would like best, had s/he waited a while for more and maybe better answers.